# angularjs - setting select element option value with JS object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJS so please bear with me.

Following is the the JSON string I am trying to bind in the `select` element:

```
[
{"Name":"Value 1","ID":1},
{"Name":"Value 2","ID":2},
{"Name":"Value 3","ID":3},
{"Name":"Value 4","ID":4}
]
```

Following is the JS object for the same:

```
function NameValue(nameValue){
    var self = this;
    self.ID = nameValue.ID;
    self.Name= nameValue.Name;    
}
```

I am parsing the above JSON string, looping through the objects and pushing items into an array using the above JS object like:

```
angular.forEach(angular.fromJson(jsonString), function (value, key) {
                $scope.Values.push(new NameValue(value));
            });
```

Following is my `select` with agularjs bindings:

```
<select ng-model="SelectedName" ng-options="x.Name for x in Values">/select>
```

When I select a value in the `select` element, the entire `NameValue` object is getting set into the `SelectedName` property which is what I am trying to do.
Now when I try to set the `SelectedName` property dynamically, the value is not getting selected and an empty `option` element is getting added in the `select` element. I used the `{{SelectedName}}` to check the value when set dynamically and when I select the same value in the `select` element manually and both are `{"ID":2,"Name":"DAO"}` which are exactly same. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you initialize the `SelectedName` in the `ng-view` directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of **ng-options** is something like this.[link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Suppose you have controller like this

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Values = [
{"Name":"Value 1","ID":1},
{"Name":"Value 2","ID":2},
{"Name":"Value 3","ID":3},
{"Name":"Value 4","ID":4}
];

$scope.SelectedByName='Value 2'; //Default setting drop down by Name property
$scope.SelectedById=4; //Default setting drop down by ID property

});
```

If you follow the below syntax then either name or Id property will be set to selected variable.

If you need default selection of drop down then you need to set the respective model in controller.(as above)

HTML :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    By name :
    <select ng-options="value.Name as value.Name for value in Values" 
    ng-model="SelectedByName" ng-change="Print()"></select> 
    Selected value is : {{SelectedByName}}
    <br>
    By ID :
    <select ng-options="value.ID as value.Name for value in Values" 
    ng-model="SelectedById" ng-change="Print()"></select>
    Selected id is : {{SelectedById}}
  </body>
```

Demo plunker [Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4ov2ANe8uT7sphu48EQ?p=preview)

Comment: looks very straight forward but what if I want to set entire object `{"ID":2,"Name":"DAO"}` in the select option value instead of `name` or `id`? They syntax which I have used for `ng-options` is setting the entire object in the `ng-model` property and setting it from the controller is not working

Comment: Check the updated plunker  [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4ov2ANe8uT7sphu48EQ?p=preview)

Comment: I have updated the plunkr with my requirement as I am getting the full object from server and binding the same to select doesn't work, link: https://plnkr.co/edit/p32Voi6pvuhTeJwHX9KX?p=preview

Comment: Use **track by** like this `<select ng-options="value as value.Name for value in Values track by value.ID" ng-model="SelectedByObj"></select>`

Comment: this is working, I have updated the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/p32Voi6pvuhTeJwHX9KX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you should initialize `SelectName` in your `$scope`.

Next you can use:

```
ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in values"
```

Can you display {{values}} in your template and it's look good? Maybe you have a problem with redraw template when data is push into value. Check this way also.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working snippet. i guess you didn't defined Values as an array, before pushing anything you have to define the variable as an array.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function NameValue(nameValue) {
  var self = this;
  self.ID = nameValue.ID;
  self.Name = nameValue.Name;
}

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.Values = [];
  $scope.jsonString = [{
    "Name": "Value 1",
    "ID": 1
  }, {
    "Name": "Value 2",
    "ID": 2
  }, {
    "Name": "Value 3",
    "ID": 3
  }, {
    "Name": "Value 4",
    "ID": 4
  }];

  angular.forEach(angular.fromJson( $scope.jsonString), function (value, key) {
                $scope.Values.push(new NameValue(value));
            });
            
    console.log($scope.Values);        
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="SelectedName" ng-options="x.Name for x in Values">/select>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i found a solution:
Don't use `ng-options` but `<option>` tag

```
<select ng-model="..."> <option ng-repeat="..."> {{ ... }} </option></select>
```